# Implementing a simple loop in Android

Tags: java, android, loops

So I come from the java world and normally when I want to loop I can just use something like:

```
while(true) {
    //code here till false
}
```

but in Android I am noticing that that kind of loop, at least in my `onCreate()` method causes an application to not be runnable. My loop I want to use is really short and calls some simple UI updates (changes the background color).

How can I implement a loop in Android that calls UI changes? Where do I put this loop? (clearly not `onCreate`) Examples/sample code would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to make UI changes periodically?

Comment: if you are doing GUI stuff behind the scenes have you taken a look at Fragment class?  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: Not even behind the scenes, I just want it to start a loop that changes the background color and then not stop till a boolean is false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On average, how many times does this loop execute? If it is a loop used to continually monitor something, you should probably use a new thread to do that. You could use a singleton and synchronize access to a few getters/setters to pass data back and forth.

You probably already know this, but if you use a `while(true)` loop, you should also have a `Thread.sleep(...)` in there so as not to lock down the CPU.

You could do something like this:

```
public class SingletonClass implements Runnable {

    private boolean someValue;

    public static final SingletonClass INSTANCE = new Test();

    private Test() {
      Thread t = new Thread(this);
      t.setDaemon(true);
      t.start();
    }

    public synchronized boolean getValue() {
      return someValue;
    }

    public synchronized void setValue(boolean value) {
      someValue = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      while (true) {
        // ... do your work here...

        // Monitor something and set values
        setValue(true);

        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
  }
}
```

In your activity you could access the necessary items like this:

```
SingletonClass.INSTANCE.getValue()
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to rethink your design.  You don't want to performing a blocking loop like that in the `onCreate()` method of your activity.  You are preventing any UI updates and may end up just hanging your application.  You will probably want to move the loop to an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

You also might try to look for an already existing method you can override/extend, like onDraw or onLayout. See the [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) documentation for further references.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to use Handler and Runnable.

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private boolean isDone = false;
private Runnable indefinateTask = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    if(isDone){
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
    } else {
        //Perform Your Operation Over Here
        mHandler.postDelayed(indefinateTask, 1);
    }


}
```

};

and in onCreate call

```
new Thread(indefinateTask).start();
```

Might Help:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Hope this help. Cheers !!!